# Can requests be handled on a separate thread?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, multithreading, async-await, httprequest

In my ASP.NET MVC web application I'm consuming a web service that sometimes might take long to respond. In this case the user might want to cancel the request and be able to make other requests. But as the server is still busy processing the previous request, the user has to wait until that one is complete. For that reason I decided to make some action methods that perform intensive IO job async, hoping  the main thread won't be blocked. But that doesn't help. Here's my method:

```
1:public class TestController:AsyncController{
2:  public async Task<ActionResult> GetString(){
3:
4:     string data=await Task<string>.Factory.StartNew(()=>{
5:           return service.GetDataAsString("name");
6:     });
7:     return View(data);
8:  }
9:}
```

The line 7 won't be executed unless the service returns the expected string , so still blocking remains. What do I have to do to make the whole action to take place in a separate thread? Do I have to go old fashion? Aren't async methods meant for this kind of things?

Comment: Probably, you looking into wrong direction. What might cause your problem, is Session Lock. Try to disable it, decorating controller with next attribute: [SessionState(SessionStateBehavior.Disabled)]

Comment: This will obviously disable the session state which is not what I want. If that's the only way, then it means I have to sacrifice either of the two: The session or the user experience. Am I correct?

Comment: @MikeJM - I think what you are after is Fire & Forget. Alternatively you can separate your action into 2 actions (One to return the view and the other to perform the service call) and perform 2 separate requests from the client.

Comment: @MikeJM If my guess was correct and thats what really caused the problem. Then yes, you will have to find golden middle. Depending on your scenario you might set SessionStateBehavior to ReadOnly. Or move problemmatic method to separate controller, for which you will be able to disable session or something else

Comment: @heymaga, but with Fire&Forget I can't return anything (or at least what I fire asyncly)

Comment: Async action is not useful in your case. You still start a new worker thread in the action to fetch data, so it's almost worse than simply using sync action. I would suggest `GetString` action simply return a message saying "Loading data...", and in the meantime you start a queued task to fetch data. Then in the UI, use ajax to check fetching status periodically (u can also use some beautiful process bar :P).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Aren't async methods meant for this kind of things?

No, `async` doesn't change the HTTP protocol. You still only have one response per request, and that response can only be sent once.

`async` *will* free up the calling thread, but on ASP.NET this just means that the thread is returned to the thread pool and is able to handle other requests; it doesn't send an HTTP response to the user. In your particular case, the code is first taking a thread from the thread pool (`StartNew`) in order to free up a thread from the thread pool (`await`), which is pointless.

There are a few solutions which should work. You could remove session state or replace this call with a SignalR hub (permitting other user requests while the old one finishes), or you can do this AJAX-style - preferably with a [reliable queue connected to an independent worker process](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn589781.aspx).